# how to use selector in piano buttons

Tags: android

When I am click on image-view they cannot perform any action they cannot change draw-able image behind image View. how can I use selector in that code.

```
rel1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
            && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE 
            && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

        Rect hitRect = new Rect();
        ImageView button;

        for(int i = 0; i < myButton1.size(); i++) {
            button = myButton1.get(i);

            button.getHitRect(hitRect);
            if (hitRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                //myButton1.get(i).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_up));   

                SoundManager.playShoot(i);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```